# Any way to automatically close the hamburger menu on :focus with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have the following source code of a mobile hamburger menu:

```
<div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="da3c1dd" class="elementor-element elementor-element-da3c1dd elementor-widget elementor-widget-spacer" data-element_type="spacer.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-spacer">
            <div class="elementor-spacer-inner"></div>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="5fa72fd" class="elementor-element elementor-element-5fa72fd elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="regulation-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#regulation-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">?מהי רגולציה</span></span></a></h4>       </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="4e7c2bc" class="elementor-element elementor-element-4e7c2bc elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#aboutmemobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">אודות</span></span></a></h4>      </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="45788e2" class="elementor-element elementor-element-45788e2 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#fit-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">?למי זה מתאים</span></span></a></h4>     </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="2a24b44" class="elementor-element elementor-element-2a24b44 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="about-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#solution-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">פתרונות</span></span></a></h4>      </div>
                </div>
                <div data-id="fcd1ddb" class="elementor-element elementor-element-fcd1ddb elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" id="contact-menu-mobile" data-element_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h4 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#contact-mobile"><span class="menu-item-text"><span align="center">צור קשר</span></span></a></h4>       </div>
                </div>
                <section data-id="23d1d02" class="elementor-element elementor-element-23d1d02 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default elementor-section elementor-inner-section" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                <div class="elementor-row">
                <div data-id="b6d5052" class="elementor-element elementor-element-b6d5052 column-contact elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-inner-column" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                <div data-id="4f72658" class="elementor-element elementor-element-4f72658 mobilemenucontact elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" id="mobilemenucontact" data-element_type="text-editor.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-text-editor elementor-clearfix"><p class="makeSmall" style="text-align: center;"><img class="email-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-1.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;<img class="facebook-mobile" src="http://mayabarber.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Untitled-2.svg" width="33" height="33">&nbsp;<label style="color: #61f6ff;" data-mce-fragment="1">|&nbsp;<span style="color: #001a71;" data-mce-fragment="1">&nbsp;052-6582643</span></label></p></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </section>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

Basically when the user presses one of the links in the menu on the phone mobile, the menu remains open and the user has to close it. What I want to achieve is to make the menu close after pressing one of the links on mobile. How is that possible with jQuery?

Here's the website: [www.mayabarber.co.il](http://www.mayabarber.co.il)
Thanks!

Comment: Figure out what class is being added to the menu to open it, remove that class on the click event of one of the links in the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this code in functions.php of your child theme.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_hamburger', 999 );
    function change_hamburger() { ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery( '.elementor-nav-menu .menu-item a' ).on("click", function(){
                jQuery('.elementor-menu-toggle').removeClass("elementor-active");
            });
        });
        </script>
    <?php }
```

Comment: This worked the best for me. Is it possible to make a 1 sec delay before it closes for some focus effect?

Comment: You can use this one
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_hamburger', 999 );
function change_hamburger() { ?>
 <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery( '.elementor-nav-menu .menu-item a' ).on("click", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('.elementor-menu-toggle').removeClass("elementor-active");            
        }, 1000 );
  });
 });
 </script>
<?php }

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect "outside click event" and trigger hider function to that.

Like this:

```
jQuery(function(){              
        menudiv=jQuery(".elementor-column-wrap");
        jQuery(window).on("click", function(event){     
        if (menudiv.has(event.target).length == 0 && !menudiv.is(event.target) ){
          menudiv.hide();
         //or  menudiv.removeClass("in or something else");
                    }}); });
```